# Get consumer utilisation via RabbitMQ Client API

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a way to get the value of the "Consumer utilisation" (as seen in the rabbitmq overview in the queues) via the RabbitMQ client? Can I ask for and react on this value via API?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in the meantime. And I think the question is important, as it is needed for bulk and monitoring purpose. But as the question was even downvoted, I will not post an answer here. It seems it's only important to me.

Answer (score 0):

Following will return the metric for all consumers:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages messages_ready state consumer_utilisation --formatter json
```

Or via REST api for a given queue:

```
curl http://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/%2F/my-queue
```

Which gives out `consumer_utilisation` as one of the returned properties. Note it returns `null` if the value is too small. For an accurate read, use `rabbitmqctl`.